# Issues with Enabling SSL in IBM Liberty 8.5.5.0 - Invalid keystore format

Tags: ssl

We have IBM liberty server (8.5.5.0) running in CICS (v5.1) region. I am getting error message listed below when we tried to activate ssl. I deleted default ssl keystore key.jks and key store recreated automatically but keep getting the same message.

I was able to view certificate in same keystore on my pc with keytool.

We also tried converting the file into IBM-1047 and IBM-037 code pages but no luck.

Error Message:

> [11/9/15 15:47:15:572 EST] 0000001d com.ibm.ws.ssl.config.WSKeyStore E CWPKI0033E: The keystore located at /xxx/resources/security/key.jks id not load because of the following error: Invalid keystore format.

We are using default ssl provided by IBM

```
<!-- SSL Feature -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<!--  Disable SSLv3 -->
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig"
   keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
   sslProtocol="TLS" />

<!--  Generate a default keystore -->
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="defaultPassword" />
```

Anybody had similar issue ? Could you please help ?

Comment: sorry, typo in the first paragraph, *sol should be read as ssl

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the keystore was empty, so I had to create it myself with Verisign CA certs.  Here are my notes:
On a mac, see java home via: /usr/libexec/java_home

keytool -list -v -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Verisign Class 3 and Class 3 G3 & G5

Aliases:

verisignclass3ca

verisignclass3g5ca

verisignclass3g3ca

keytool -export -alias verisignclass3ca -file verisign_c3.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

keytool -export -alias verisignclass3g3ca -file verisign_c3g3.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

keytool -export -alias verisignclass3g5ca -file verisign_c3g5.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

keytool -import -trustcacerts -file verisign_c3.crt -alias verisign_c3ca -keystore key.jks -storepass worklight

Enter keystore password:

Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias

Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]:Y

keytool -import -trustcacerts -file verisign_c3g3.crt -alias verisign_c3g3ca -keystore key.jks -storepass worklight

keytool -import -trustcacerts -file verisign_c3g5.crt -alias verisign_c3g5ca -keystore key.jks -storepass worklight